# share colors between pie and column in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have chart like this image 
this chart created with pie,spline and column.column display correct value y-axis and pie display precent of y-axis and need each peice of pie that relate to column have a same color.im traying to use [color array](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) in highchart but it dosent work.

[image: Highcharts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [colors](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors%28%29) where number of elements will be equal number of categories. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/3EkbA/2/

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        colors: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black' ],
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Jane',
            colorByPoint: 'true',
            data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        },{
            type: 'pie',
            data: [14, 15, 16, 17,14],
            center: [100, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seing your code for the cart, it's hard to say the best way to sort this out. However, one option is to specify the colour of each point in the series (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data)

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

This way you have absolute comtrol over the colour of every point in each series.

Comment: no, the data come from server with ajax calling and i cant set color for each data

Comment: If you post your chart code, we may be able to identify other solutions.